# Is there a way to use PHP to check whether my mail content is spam?

Tags: php, email

The idea is before i send the mail , I would like to use some code to check the content whether it use spam phrase .  Here is some simple code

```
function isSpam($text)
{
    $pattern = "/\b(actual|filter|removed|because|it|contained|obscenities)\b/i";

    if(preg_match($pattern, $text, $match))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The question are:

1. Are there any way to improve the code such as check the occur time not only check if it is exist?
2. Are there any plugin or code exist already so I do not have to redo it?
3. Bayesian Spam Filter is all about a mail inbox ? Is it useful as an **outgoing email filter**?

Thank you for helping

Comment: Is *this* the kind of spam you get? Bayesian filtering needs only samples of spam and ham (good mail) to work, so try implementing it.

Comment: @Blender: re-read the question. It's the kind of mail he's sending to other people.

Comment: I did. So he's sending spam and can't stop? I'm thinking this is some automated email system that can be used by others.

Comment: @Blender Maybe he's just got a split personality. Or an evil twin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check any content if it contains any spam messages with a nice to use plugin called Akismet it is free and used by most of the CMS and blogging application like wordpress etc.

check out the link http://akismet.com/

the library itself is very easy to implement, just download the library from there website and use the provided API from there documentation. and you are good to go. i have found this to be very effective for myself.

Comment: Is it as simple as just input a html/ text file in it and I will get the result? I am going to register for an account , good suggestion Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If your server is equipped with SpamAssassin, then you could use this API: http://ppadron.blog.br/2010/05/04/php-api-to-spamassassin-spamd-protocol/ ( it might be a bit outdated, but it wouldn't be an insurmountable task to bring it up the date ).

I'm quite sure that other spam-prevention tools would have similar capabilities.